# VueJs 2 emit custom event firing, but not being "heard"

Tags: javascript, events, vue.js

Probably not possible, but I have an object that extends Vue/ VueComponent (tried both)  that `$emits` a custom event that would normally be caught on its parent.

Please see this pen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MvmeQp?editors=0011 and watch the console.

```
class nonVueComponent extends Vue {
  constructor(age,...args){
    super(args)
    console.log('new Blank Obj')

    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('customEvent event does fire, but nothing hears it. Probably because it isnt in the DOM?', age)
      this.$emit('customEvent', `custom event from nonVueComponent...${age}`)  
    },500)

  }
}

Vue.component('test', {
  template: `<div>
               {{content}}
                <child :childAge="age" @customEvent="customEvent"></child>
                <child-secondary @secondaryEvent="customEvent"></child-secondary>
  </div>`,  
  props: {},
  data () {
    return {
      content: 'hello from component!',
      age : 20
    }
  },
  methods : {
    customEvent(data){
      console.log('PARENT: custom event triggered!', data)
      this.content = data
    },
    secondaryEvent(data){
      console.log('PARENT: !!secondary custom event triggered', data)
      this.content = data
    }
  }
})

Vue.component('child',{
  template: `<div>+- child {{childAge}}</div>`,
  props: ['childAge'],
  data () {
    outsideOfVue: new nonVueComponent(this.childAge)
  }
})

Vue.component('child-secondary',{
  template: `<div>+- secondary event</div>`,
  mounted(){
    setTimeout( ()=>{
      this.$emit('secondaryEvent', 'from secondary event....')  
    },125 )
   }
})

let vm = new Vue({ el: '#app'})
```

Aside from using an eventBus, is there any other way to get the event up and out from the `<child>` ? Maybe make the `nonVueComponent` a mixin?

Thanks.

Comment: What you are trying only works between parent&child components, not arbitrary instances of the Vue constructor. that "nonComponent" is essentially an event bus. Since I have no idea how you use that "nonComponent", I can't really suggest a different solution or judge if it could be solved with a mixin.

Comment: Oh, the codepen shows more, will check it out ...

Comment: in Vuex chrome tools, the event emitted is registered in the root. I think this just won't work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

code:https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EvmmKa?editors=0011

The object who emits the event should be the instace of child-secondary.
Try to convey the instance to the nonVueComponent's constructor.

```
class nonVueComponent extends Vue {
  constructor(age,comp,...args){
    super(args)
    console.log('new Blank Obj')

    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('customEvent event does fire, but nothing hears it. Probably because it isnt in the DOM?', age)
      comp.$emit('customEvent', `custom event from nonVueComponent...${age}`)  
    },500)

  }
}
```

Comment: Ah. Yes. That's clever, and makes sense.